# How do I set one background image to all pages in blazor wasm?

Tags: c#, html, css

I am trying to add one background image to my all my pages except for the login and the register pages.

I am only able to put them manually on the login and register pages.

i tried to use mainlayout but to no luck, any help could be appreciated.

**This is the CSS in the Mainlayout**

```
` body {
    height: 100%;

    background-Image: url("wwwroot/css/Image/bankbgrd.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

`

Comment: We can't help you without more information. You should share a bit more about your HTML, the error you get (if any), ...

Comment: @Lynxi I am trying to set thee same background picture to all my pages. i managed to manually add the image to the login page (razor) with this code 
    `  ** body {
        height: 100%;
   
  background-Image: url("wwwroot/css/Image/bankbgrd.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
 } 
** `
i then went ahead and put in this code in the body section of my css in Mainlayout.razor.css.

Comment: @Lynxi the problem is that the mainlayout image does not show.